# Prove that $\mathscr{F}[f] \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Let $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ (square integrable functions), I'm trying to prove that his Fourier transform also does: $\mathscr{F}[f] \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$.

I have tried to bound it

\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}|\ \hat{f}(\omega)\ |^2 d\omega &= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \left| \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(t)\ e^{-i\omega t} \right|^2 d\omega \\
&\leq \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \left( \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}|\ f(t)\ e^{-i\omega t}\ | \right)^2 d\omega \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \left( \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}|\ f(t)\ | \right)^2 d\omega \\
\end{align}

but the last expression is not necessarily finite. Any help will be helpful!

Comment: The last expression is only finite if $f \equiv 0$. Proving that the Fourier transform maps $L^2$ to $L^2$ is a very length proof no matter which way you do it. I suggest you look up a text on Fourier analysis. Any full answer will be way too long to expect someone to recreate it, especially when it is in a number of texts. Moreover, your definition for the Fourier transform of an $L^2$ function is very incorrect. The Fourier transform is not defined as an integral transform on $L^2$, but is instead defined via a limiting procedure from $L^1(\Bbb R)\cap L^2(\Bbb R)$.

Comment: The reason for this is that the Fourier transform as you want it to be only exists for $L^1(\Bbb R)$ functions but there are a wealth of functions in $L^2(\Bbb R)$ that are not $L^1(\Bbb R)$ functions, however $L^1(\Bbb R)\cap L^2(\Bbb R)$ is dense in $L^2(\Bbb R)$, so proving properties on $L^1(\Bbb R)\cap L^2(\Bbb R)$ allows us to easily lift these properties to all of $L^2(\Bbb R)$ since the Fourier transform is a bounded operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f$ be absolutely and absolutely square integrable on $\mathbb{R}$. Then,
$$
        \overline{\hat{f}(s)}=\overline{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)e^{-ist}dt}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\overline{f(t)}e^{ist}dt = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\overline{f(-t')}e^{-ist'}dt'
$$
Let $g(t)=\overline{f(-t)}$. Then $\overline{\hat{f}(s)}=\hat{g}(s)$. By the convolution theorem, $f\star g$ is absolutely integrable
$$
     |\hat{f}(s)|^2 = \hat{f}(s)\hat{g}(s)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\widehat{(f\star g)}(s)
$$
Then you can evaluate the $L^2$ norm of the Fourier transform
\begin{align}
       \int_{\infty}^{\infty}|\hat{f}(s)|^2ds & =\left.\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\widehat{f\star g}(s)e^{isx}ds\right|_{x=0} \\
   & = (f\star g)(0) \\
   & = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)g(0-t)dt \\
   & = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|f(t)|^2dt.
\end{align}
This is an outline of the shortest argument I know. Everything goes through if $f\star g$ is differentiable at $0$ because then you have the classical Fourier inversion result at $0$, and that's what is being used in the last equation string. At least it gives you an idea of why the result is true for the Fourier transform.

Comment: When you do the change $t \rightarrow - t'$, $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\overline{f(-t')}e^{-ist'}dt'$ should change the sign, right?

Comment: It would, except that the new integral is $\int_{\infty}^{-\infty} = -\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}$.

Comment: Got it now, thanks!